# Is this overlay on click of Request Topic button expected?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, documentation-topics

I'm not sure if it is cosmetic UI defect or is it intentional, but to me, it surely doesn't look too promising. When I click on <kbd>Request Topic</kbd>  button on [MySql Documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/3307/select#t=201705290701440113087), there is full page overlay coming over the content, Though I'm able to write in a TextBox and can access other page controls but overall it doesn't look too good to end users.

[image]

I can see the similar with <kbd>Propose a New Tag</kbd> button as well on [Documentation's home page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. This z-index madness will be resolved with the next production build.